# Android, MOUSE_OUT?

Tags: android

When the user clicks on an image view my app does stuff, and when the user finger goes up, it also does stuff, my question is, how can I check when the users finger strays off the image view, but is still pressing the screen, sort of a MOUSE_OUT in flash... so far I have:

```
 myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to catch `ACTION_MOVE` events, and see if they stray outside the `ImageView` bounds.

In order to do this, you'll need to catch the events not on the ImageView, but on a View that covers it and the surrounding area (as the ImageView won't be able to see interaction outside its own bounds). Depending on how much space you have around your `ImageView`, and whether there are other elements you want to interact with by touch immediately around it, this could get slightly tricky, as you'll need to work out at `ACTION_DOWN` which element was touched.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to get the current x and y value of the touch in action move?

Comment: [yes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX()).